# What sword is pictured in Goblin Sword's app icon?

Tags: goblin-sword

What sword is this, can you get it, & where?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this guide](https://kkatlas.com/2015/08/22/game-guide-goblin-sword/) (reference image below), the sword appears to be Dragonslayer. [Another guide](http://www.dtgre.com/2014/09/goblin-sword-solution-for-all-levels.html) says you can get the Dragonslayer by purchasing it from the dealer/merchant for 3000.

[image]